# how can i change the value of checkbox when i select a value from select input with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, checkbox

i want to learn that when i select a value from select input how can i change the value of checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="id" value="" id="mycheckbox1">

<select name="cat-1" id="myselectbox1">
    <option value="">Choose</option>      
    <option value="100">Value1</option>
    <option value="200">Value2</option>       
</select>
```

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="" id="mycheckbox1">

<select name="cat-1" id="myselectbox1">
      <option value="">Choose</option>
      
   
   <option value="100">Value1</option>
           
   
   
   <option value="200">Value2</option>
           
   
    </select>

Comment: Why would you want to change the value of a checkbox? What is the usecase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to?

Anyway:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // on page load
  document.getElementById("myselectbox1").addEventListener("change", function() {
    document.getElementById("mycheckbox1").value = this.value;
  });
  document.getElementById("mycheckbox1").addEventListener("change", function() {
    console.log(this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="id" value="" id="mycheckbox1">

<select name="cat-1" id="myselectbox1">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
  <option value="100">Value1</option>
  <option value="200">Value2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Another question?

Comment: i asked new one, bottom of page. if u help me i'll be so happy

Answer (score 1):

```js
function updateCheckbox() {
  var val = document.getElementById("myselectbox1").value;
  document.getElementById("mycheckbox1").checked = true;
  document.getElementById("mycheckbox1").value = val;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="id" value="" id="mycheckbox1">

<select onChange="updateCheckbox()" name="cat-1" id="myselectbox1">
  <option selected disabled>Choose</option>
  <option value="100">Value1</option>
  <option value="200">Value2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The question is about changing the **value** of the checkbox, not its `check` state - It's not the same thing :)

Comment: Sorry, I just overlooked the question. I have updated the answer now.

Comment: It is not recommended to have inline event handlers

Answer (score 0):

may i ask one more question

i changed my checkbox value if i have one more select input which id cat-2
how can i change name of cat-2 to chosen value of cat-1

For example;
if i choose value1 ( its value=100)
i want to change name of cat-2 to cat-100

````
```
<input type="checkbox" name="id" value="" id="mycheckbox1">

<select name="cat-1" id="myselectbox1">
<option value="">Choose</option>      
<option value="100">Value1</option>
<option value="200">Value2</option>       
</select>

<select name="cat-2" id="myselectbox2">
<option value="">Choose</option>      
<option value="300">Value3</option>
<option value="400">Value4</option>       
</select>

```
````

Comment: Please do not use the answers to ask more questions

Comment: What is the reason for changing names of fields - that is very non-standard

Comment: its about my project and i have to get that value

Comment: document.getElementById("myselectbox2").name = "c"+this.value;
  });

Comment: could you look that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62365008/change-name-attribute-of-select-with-jquery