# How to change the name of a select tag attribute with jquery

Tags: javascript

First of all,
when I select a value from select tag. Change the input value of the checkbox.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // on page load
  document.getElementById("myselectbox1").addEventListener("change", function() {
    document.getElementById("mycheckbox1").value = this.value;
  });
  document.getElementById("mycheckbox1").addEventListener("change", function() {
    console.log(this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="id" value="" id="mycheckbox1">

<select name="cat-1" id="myselectbox1">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
  <option value="100">Value1</option>
  <option value="200">Value2</option>
</select>
```

How can I change the name of cat-2 to the chosen value of cat-1

For example;
if I choose value1 ( its value=100)
I want to change the name of cat-2 to cat-100

```
<input type="checkbox" name="id" value="" id="mycheckbox1">

<select name="cat-1" id="myselectbox1">
<option value="">Choose</option>      
<option value="100">Value1</option>
<option value="200">Value2</option>       
</select>

<select name="cat-2" id="myselectbox2">
<option value="">Choose</option>      
<option value="300">Value3</option>
<option value="400">Value4</option>       
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just continue my script from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62363989/how-can-i-change-the-value-of-checkbox-when-i-select-a-value-from-select-input-w)

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // on page load
  document.getElementById("myselectbox1").addEventListener("change", function() {
    document.getElementById("mycheckbox1").value = this.value;
    const sel2 =  document.getElementById("myselectbox2");
    if (sel2 && this.value) sel2.name="c-"+this.value;
  });
  // check to see the change
  document.getElementById("mycheckbox1").addEventListener("change", function() {
    console.log(this.value);
  });
  // select to see the change
  document.getElementById("myselectbox2").addEventListener("change", function() {
    console.log(this.name,this.value)
  })  
  
  
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="id" value="" id="mycheckbox1">

<select name="cat-1" id="myselectbox1">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
  <option value="100">Value1</option>
  <option value="200">Value2</option>
</select>


<select name="cat-2" id="myselectbox2">
<option value="">Choose</option>      
<option value="300">Value3</option>
<option value="400">Value4</option>       
</select>
```